# elementary question on retrieving value from getJson call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC 2 application. On the client side there is a function that is making a call to a controller, and a value is being returned, but I can't manage to put it in a JavaScript variable for subsequent use.

Here is the JSON being returned by the controller (this part is working fine, I checked with Fiddler):

```
{"CompanyID":781}
```

And here is my JS/jQuery function:

```
function getSelectedCompanyID() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            var cid = "";
            $.getJSON("/Company/GetLatestCompanyID/", function (json) {
                cid = json.CompanyID;
            });
            return cid;
        }
```

Thanks.

**Edit**:
Just to clarify, the problem seems to be with this line:

```
cid = json.CompanyID;
```

or with the JSON call itself. The retrieved value is not being placed into the JS variable.

Comment: It definitely is being placed there. However, by the time that happens, the `return cid;` statement is just a distant memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call is **asynchronous**. The callback function you pass in to "$.getJSON()" won't actually be called until the HTTP request completes, which will be a **long time** after the outer function has returned.

The way to code in order to deal with this fact is to put into that callback function all the necessary logic to handle the results.  That is, instead of writing the code to expect that outer function to return a value, put all that code **inside** the callback itself.

*edit* — here's the timeline of activity, to clarify:

1. Something happens on your page, triggering (among other things) a call to "getSelectedCompanyID()".
2. The "getSelectedCompanyID" function calls "$.getJSON()", passing in a URL and an anonymous function that, **upon completion of the HTTP request,** will set a local variable in the outer closure to some of the returned data.
3. The jQuery code does a flurry of work to set up the XMLHttpRequest, starts it up, and then returns to "getSelectedCompanyID()".
4. The `return` statment at the end of the "getSelectedCompanyID()" function is evaluated, and that function exits.
5. The code that called "getSelectedCompanyID()" stares in disappointment at the null value returned from "getSelectedCompanyID()".
   *and then a   l o n g   time later:*
6. The HTTP request completes as a response comes back from your server.
7. The jQuery wrapper code deserializes the JSON response and calls the anonymous handler passed in back at step 2.
8. The anonymous handler function sticks a value from the returned JSON object into the "cid" variable, and then it exits.

Comment: I know it's asynchronous. This function is responding to a client-side event on the page. The problem is not *when* it is being executed, but the fact that it is not putting the returned value into the cid variable.

Comment: It is getting put into the variable.  You've already returned from the function by the time it does it though.

Comment: @draconis the problem is that your outer function "getSelectedCompanyID" cannot be made to **wait** for the asynchronous call to complete. Immediately after **starting** the asynchronous operation, the JavaScript interpreter will execute that `return` statement. Many milliseconds later, the asynchronous call will complete.

Comment: @draconis: It is **exactly** the problem *when* it will be executed.

Comment: @Pointy: read through your detailed response, I understand the problem now, thanks. Is there any way to hold up Javascript execution until the asynchronous request completes?

Comment: @draconis no, in a browser environment things are always asynchronous. It takes some time to become familiar with that programming style, but once you do you'll realize that it really isn't any harder. It's just different.

Comment: @pointy: thanks for your help. I was trying to do something which is apparently impossible - making one asynchronous call dependent on information supplied by another asynchronous call.

Comment: But surely there is some way to attach an event handler to the ajax call, such that, on successful completion of the call, another function is triggered??

Comment: Yes, exactly - that's that little function you pass in. What you can do is have that little function (where you're setting "cid") instead pass that "cid" value to some *other* function, one that does all the work you need to do with the company ID.  In other words, that handler function you pass to $.getJSON is exactly what you describe as an ajax "event handler" :-)